# Sporadic console message - Request failed with status code 429

Tags: node.js, axios

I have this error or warning that seems to come up sporadically in the console. In the browser, the request will just hang a little and then eventually load, or eventually timeout. Other times the page will load normally.

**Error**

```
getWeather: Error: Request failed with status code 429
```

For brevity, this is part of my code that seems to produce the error

```
// get the weather from open weather map
let getWeather = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    getCity.then( 
        apiData => {
            axios.all([
                axios.get(apiData.weatherUrl),
                axios.get(apiData.imageUrl)
            ])
            .then(axios.spread((weatherRes, imageRes) => {
                const weather = weatherRes.data;
                apiData.weatherForcast = `It's ${weather.main.temp} degrees Celcius in ${weather.name}`;
                const imageApiData = imageRes.data;
                apiData.largeImageURL = imageApiData.hits[0]['largeImageURL'];
                resolve(apiData);
            }))
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error("getWeather: "+error)
            })
        }, 
        error => { 
            reject(error); 
            res.end("Could not query the get weather");
        } 
    )
});
```

The error code is related to too many requests. What's causing this and how do I fix it? Perhaps you could dumb it down a little because I'm a bit new to Node. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not too late to answer your question, but I encountered the same issue when working on a project so perhaps this might still be of use to you.

The code 429 translates to a client error: `Too Many Requests`.

The API you are trying to call is probably limiting you to do an x amount of requests per hour and you have exceeded it. Check if you are calling the API multiple times, if that is the case you could try to call it just once and place all the data you need into an object or other sorts of data structure then you can just work with that data instead of calling the API.

Hope this helps!